# Macbeth ColorChecker for WPF

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Is there a C# code or a WPF tool for Macbeth ColorChecker finder?
that I can use as a reference for my project.

Comment: Do you have to process 100's of images which may or may not have a Macbeth chart in it or not, possibly only in part? If yes, it may be a worthwhile project. If not, a GUI to click on four corners and rectify the quadrangle is all you need...

Comment: at the moment i need only a few pics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the macduff project on github https://github.com/ryanfb/macduff - unfortunately this is not really robust: If the chart is not frontal this leads to misdetection in my experiments. The license is nice though - could be a good place to build upon...

Keigo Hirakawa has posted Matlab Code http://campus.udayton.edu/~ISSL/index.php/macbeth-colorchecker-finder/ for locating color checkers. Code is available, the license is a little more restrictive (non-commercial), not yet tested